# c# how to check if a number is infinity

Tags: c#

i have a little problem. I have two double variables which each has the value 1*10^250. Now if I multiplicate these two values I get a result which is also a double variable. The problem is that the result of the multiplication gives me the value infinity but I want to prevent this and give an error message. So it would be nice if someone know how to identify if a number is infinity.

Answer (score 21):

How about the [`Double.IsInfinity(Double)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.isinfinity(v=vs.110).aspx) method?

```
Double.IsInfinity(3.0 / 0)
```

**See also**

- [`IsPositiveInfinity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.ispositiveinfinity(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`IsNegativeInfinity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.isnegativeinfinity(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`PositiveInfinity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.positiveinfinity(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`NegativeInfinity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.negativeinfinity(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 9):

use

```
double.IsInfinity(theDoubleNumber);
```

you can also use `double.IsNegativeInfinity()`, `double.IsPositiveInfinity()`, `double.NaN()`, `double.MaxValue()`, `double.MinValue()` for similar purpose

Answer (score 2):

try this..

```
if (Double.IsInfinity(SampleVar))
{
  // Put your logic here.
}
if (Double.IsNaN(SampleVar))
{
  // Put your logic here.
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This was suggested in the other answers in 2017 . Duplicate answers should not be posted.

Answer (score 1):

To compliment the high voted answers, here's a quick code snippet to demonstrate their usage.

```
double d1 = Math.Pow(10, 250); // = 1*10^250
double d2 = Math.Pow(10, 250);
double d3 = d1 * d2; 

Console.WriteLine (d1);
Console.WriteLine (d2);
Console.WriteLine (d3);

Console.WriteLine (Double.IsInfinity(d3)); //true (using a method)
Console.WriteLine (d3 == Double.PositiveInfinity); //true (comparing to a value)
Console.WriteLine (d3 == double.PositiveInfinity); //true (note that "Double" or "double" can be used)

Console.WriteLine (d3 == Double.NaN); //false
Console.WriteLine (d3 == Double.MaxValue); //false
```

Answer (score -3):

It is enough to extract the logarithms of the 2 variables and then to add them.
Simplyt before you multiply to catch the error, if the variables to be multiplied are A and B follow this pseudo-code :

```
#include <math.h>
Double A,B,L1,L2;
Boolean MYERROR;
main(){
L1 = LOG10(A);
L2 = LOG10(B);
If( (L1 + L2) > DBL_MAX_10_EXP){ MYERROR = true;}else{MYERROR = false;}
}
```

Comment: The question is about C#, and this isn't even valid C. Nor does this work if either number is not positive. It also excludes cases where `a * b` is still representible despite the exponent exceeding the maximum for a normalized number. The general technique has applications, but it's much more involved than checking for infinity.

Comment: I agree, it can only work for positive ones. The solution I gave is simply the question that seemed to be about positive numbers. I also wrote that it was a pseudo-code, so neither c # or c, we agree.

On the other hand, it is true that the double whose exponent exceeds the predicted values are quite storable. But they can cause fatal errors, so it is advisable to avoid them.