# Is it valid check for infinity with the equals operator?

Tags: c#, floating-point, equality, infinity

[c# how to check if a number is infinity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42733637/c-sharp-how-to-check-if-a-number-is-infinity)

Answer: `Double.IsInfinity`, `Double.IsPosiviteInfinity`, etc.

So now comes my question: Is it valid to simply do:

```
double d = Double.PositiveInfinity;
if(d == Double.PositiveInfinity)
{
    //
}
```

It seems to be working, BUT! If things are that simple, why does the aforementioned question's answers recommend `Double.IsPositiveInfinity` instead? Why is this method provided at all?

This makes me wonder if there are any caveats with checking for infinity by means of the `==` operator... are there?

Comment: You can see in the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/double.cs,db0603318ee4c493,references) that the IsPositiveInfinity method is doing the same comparison. IsInfinity is slightly optimized to only look for the bits necessary by doing a bit mask and one comparison instead of two. I suppose these are provided because it is sort of an anti-pattern to compare floating point numbers for exact equality because their precision can be changed based on subtle factors. Also the semantics of NaN discourage it.

Answer (score 0):

Those things are methods, not properties (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.ispositiveinfinity(v=vs.110).aspx ). As far as I know, you are expected to use them like:

```
 if (double.IsPositiveInfinity(d)) { }
```

Comment: Ooops, I messed up.  I saw your `Double.PositiveInfinity` and read it as `double.IsPositiveInfinity()`, which is the only way I ever checked for this kind of value.  I've always used the methods for roughly the same reasons that @mike Z points out: "because it is sort of an anti-pattern to compare floating point numbers for exact equality"